# Compile time size of data member std::array in non-class template (C++14)

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, stdarray

#### Compile-time inspection std::array data member for its (compile time) size

I need to statically assert that the compile-time size of a non-constexpr data member of type `std::array`, say `arr_`, of a **non-template** class is equal to a given (externally provided) constant. The static assertion will be done from inside the class, meaning `arr_` is accessible, but I cannot rely on any stored constant (nor a non-type template parameter) for its size. I.e., the assertion needs to  rely solely on "some inspection" of the `arr_` data member.

I would basically be done if the `constexpr` `std::array<>::size()`/`std::array<>::max_size()` was static member functions (`decltype(arr_)::size()`/`decltype(arr_)::max_size()`) instead of a non-static member functions.

I have a working approach using  function template argument deduction on a pointer-to-data-member for the `arr_` member, but I'm wondering if there is an easier/neater approach.

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

// Defined/provided from elsewhere.
constexpr std::size_t kArraySize = 12U;
constexpr std::size_t kAnotherArraySize = 12U;

template <typename T, typename U, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t size_of_data_member_array(std::array<T, N> U::*) {
    return N;
}

class Foo {
    std::array<int, kArraySize> arr_;
    static_assert(size_of_data_member_array(&Foo::arr_) == kAnotherArraySize, "");
};

int main() {}
```

Comment: May I ask why you mention `std::array::max_size()` (_the maximum number of elements the container is able to hold due to system or library implementation limitations_) while you ask for the actual size of the member. var? Shouldn't it be `std::array::size()` in this case?

Comment: @Scheff In this case both works, but indeed `std::array<>::size()` is probably a more logical choice (regarding `max_size`: _"Because each `std::array<T, N>` is a fixed-size container, the value returned by `max_size` equals `N` (which is also the value returned by size) "_). Updated, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I really can't get the point. A st::array has compile time constant size and the size can be requested by size(). So what is the missing part?

Comment: @Klaus Albeit the `size()` non-static member function is `constexpr`, it will not be so for a non-`constexpr` array (such as the data member in this example). However, as [@GiovanniCerretani shows in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63739049/4573247), the missing part was not much (use `decltype` to instantiate a temporary and invoke `size()` on that one).

Comment: @dfri I should have read the [Notes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/max_size#Notes) as well: _Because each std::array<T, N> is a fixed-size container, the value returned by max_size equals N (which is also the value returned by size)_ Sorry, my fault.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard provides a static version of `array::size` under the name [`tuple_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/tuple_size):

```
#include <array>
#include <tuple> // for std::tuple_size_v

static_assert(std::tuple_size<decltype(arr_)>::value == kAnotherArraySize, "");
static_assert(std::tuple_size_v<decltype(arr_)> == kAnotherArraySize); // C++17
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create an instance of an array with the same type of `Foo::arr_` within the static assertion:

```
class Foo {
    std::array<int, kArraySize> arr_;
    static_assert(decltype(arr_){}.size() == kAnotherArraySize, "");
};
```

See [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/4MYPsK).

**Note**: this works only if the array value type is a POD or has a default constexpr constructor.

Comment: could also use `declvar`

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie `array::size` can't be used in an unevaluated operand.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Assuming you mean `declval`, how could we use that here? It needs to be told the type to use, which itself needs to come from `decltype`... or we would need to explicitly write `std::array<T, N>`, in which case you already know `N`, which defeats the point of the question. Or am I being dense?

Answer (score 2):

Just to offer another option, you can do partial specialization on template variables.

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

// Defined/provided from elsewhere.
constexpr std::size_t kArraySize = 12U;
constexpr std::size_t kAnotherArraySize = 12U;

template <typename T>
constexpr std::size_t array_size = 0;

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t array_size<std::array<T, N>> = N;

class Foo {
    std::array<int, kArraySize> arr_;
    static_assert(array_size<decltype(arr_)> == kAnotherArraySize, "");
};

int main() {}
```

Answer (score 2):

To offer yet another option using SFINAE:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <array>

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_array_v = false;

template <typename T, size_t N>
constexpr bool is_array_v<std::array<T, N>> = true;

template <typename Array, std::enable_if_t<is_array_v<Array>, int> = 0>
constexpr size_t array_size_v = std::tuple_size<Array>::value;

static_assert(array_size_v<std::array<int, 5>> == 5); // OK
static_assert(array_size_v<int> == 5);                // Won't compile
```

Unlike the other proposals, this will catch misuse of `array_size_v` at compile time, so entering an `int` and other types which are not `std::array` won't work.

Comment: `declval` doesn't work either, because it can only be used in an unevaluated operand.

Comment: @L.F. well, now it uses `tuple_size`, so that will work.

Comment: Well then we can just use `tuple_size` directly :D

Comment: @L.F. except that `std::tuple_size` will accept any type that overloads it, not just a `std::array`.

Comment: Indeed.  That may be desirable though - other kinds of tuple-like classes are supported as well.

Comment: Note that you only cover the non-cv-qualified case above, whereas e.g. `is_array_v<const std::array<int, 42>` and `is_array_v<volatile std::array<int, 42>` both results in `false`.